# How to disable Keyboard appearance animation in React Native

Tags: react-native, keyboard

When the user start focusing the text input. The keyboard will be moved in from the bottom. How can i avoid this animation when start focusing?

I just read the doc of TextInput, Keyboard. But no related parameter is mentioned in the doc:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard.html

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Comment: So you don't want the keyboard appears? Or you don't want the keyboard appears from the bottom?

Comment: Can you elaborate your case with your example code ?

Comment: I don't want the keyboard appears from the bottom. Instead of this, i would like the keyboard appears immediately (without the animation). And i think elaborating the example code is not applicable because it is hard to explain with code. Thanks !

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, It's not supported.

RN doesn't support a way to set `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];`, which is the way to disable the animation for iOS, or `setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);` for Android.