# Is that possible to force keyboard gone immediately in React Native?

Tags: react-native, keyboard

Is there anyway to hide keyboard immediately, like set index -1 or whatever?

Currently, after keyboard.dismiss, you need to wait for a bit time to fully hide keyboard. Thanks.

Comment: RN doesn't support a way to dismiss the keyboard without animation https://stackoverflow.com/a/55545554/1394414

Comment: Ah ok, thanks!@EstevãoLucas