# Keyboard automatically shown after open the screen

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building the app in `react native` and `expo`.
I want to make the screen that when I go to this screen the keyboard should be already opened without possibility to close it.
I mean - the screen should look like in the photo below just after I open this

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `autoFocus` prop of the `TextInput` in order to open the keyboard on mount of the screen (e.g. it is triggered in the `useEffect`).

```js
const [number, setNumber] = useState()

<View keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
<TextInput
   autoFocus={true}
   onChangeText={x => setNumber(x)}
   value={number}
   blurOnSubmit={false}
/>
</View>
```

Use `blurOnSubmit={false}` in order to prevent keyboard dismis on enter and use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'` on the parent view in order to prevent dismiss if tapping outside the screen.

Comment: ok, its fine, but with this option when I open the screen, the keyboard slides from down - is there possibility to have the keyboard already shown without this animation? What I want to achieve is the same what `Tinder` has when you go to the screen with phone number input - the keyboard is already shown.

Comment: This is not possible without implementing a native module for ios and android (and even then I am not 100% convinced that this is possible). The keyboard is triggered natively. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581681/how-to-disable-keyboard-appearance-animation-in-react-native

Comment: ahh, the pain of cross platform technologies :( thanks for the answer

Comment: I have got one another question. When I am on the screen which the photo I printed above in question and I go to next screen by `Continue` button and then go back to this screen again, keyboard does not show automatically. Do you know how to fix this?